# Botpress|Slack Bot access request url (using ngrok)

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I am building a Slack Bot with Botpress and managed to interact with it successfully but fail at utelizing the buttons. I can click on them in the chat after the bot has posted them but then i don't know how to access the request url that the bot is firing the json to. 
The documentation says:

*"Any interactions with message buttons, menus, or dialogs will be sent to a URL you specify. Learn more."*

But what does that even mean ? Im using ngrok to create the given URL but have no clue how to access the payload that is being sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

Slack will send a request to your app after you pressed a button.

You therefore need to specify the URL of your app that receives the request from Slack. Its called "Request URL" and you can find it in the management page for your Slack app under "Interactive Components".

There you put the full ngrok URL that points to your app. e.g. `https://12345.ngrok.io/myapps/cmd.php`.

Comment: I am facing below error while clicking on a button within slack. https://github.com/botpress/botpress/issues/876

Can you please help with the steps to integrate buttons in slack using botpress. I am using Botpress X version 10.31.0.